# RSpec each block and block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

What is the difference between these blocks in RSpec and which situation to use before block

```
before(:each)
end

before
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference. `:each` is the default option. Unless you specify `:each`/`:all`, then `:each` is used.

Answer (score 0):

:each is the scope, it can be :each which runs the block before each example, or :all which runs the block before all examples.

You use it to run a block before each or all examples to set up your text fixture. you always have to pass a block to before, thus, your syntax above is slightly incorrect, it should be

```
before(:each) do
  ...
end
```

or
    before(:each) { ... }

see    https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks